# C# Regular Expression excluding a string

Tags: c#, regex

I got a collection of string and all i want for regex is to collect all started with http..

> href="http://www.test.com/cat/1-one_piece_episodes/"href="http://www.test.com/cat/2-movies_english_subbed/"href="http://www.test.com/cat/3-english_dubbed/"href="http://www.exclude.com"

this is my regular expression pattern..

```
href="(.*?)[^#]"
```

and return this

```
href="http://www.test.com/cat/1-one_piece_episodes/"
href="http://www.test.com/cat/2-movies_english_subbed/"
href="http://www.xxxx.com/cat/3-english_dubbed/"
href="http://www.exclude.com"
```

what is the pattern for excluding the last match.. or excluding matches that has the **exclude** domain inside like href="http://www.exclude.com"

**EDIT:**
for multiple exclusion

```
href="((?:(?!"|\bexclude\b|\bxxxx\b).)*)[^#]"
```

Comment: Would you want the url `http://www.test.com/fish/exclude` included? what about `http://www.exclude.co.uk` or `http://www.exclude.test.com`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

@ridgerunner and me would change the regex to:

```
href="((?:(?!\bexclude\b)[^"])*)[^#]"
```

It matches all `href` attributes as long as they don't end in `#` and don't contain the word `exclude`.

**Explanation:**

```
href="     # Match href="
(          # Capture...
 (?:       # the following group:
  (?!      # Look ahead to check that the next part of the string isn't...
   \b      # the entire word
   exclude # exclude
   \b      # (\b are word boundary anchors)
  )        # End of lookahead
  [^"]     # If successful, match any character except for a quote
 )*        # Repeat as often as possible
)          # End of capturing group 1
[^#]"      # Match a non-# character and the closing quote.
```

To allow multiple "forbidden words":

```
href="((?:(?!\b(?:exclude|this|too)\b)[^"])*)[^#]"
```

Comment: parsing "href="((?:(?!"|\bexclude\b).)*[^#]"" - Not enough )'s     its ok now.. i just read the explanation..  href="((?:(?!"|\bexclude\b).)*)[^#]"

Comment: additional question sir.. how about if i exclude additional string **xxxx** ?

Comment: @vrynxzent: Sorry, I had dropped a closing parenthesis. But you have found the correct solution, obviously :)

Comment: +1 for this awesome explanation! I know regex editors that do this but somehow, looking at their output I was always perplexed. Yours is so much succinct!

Comment: @ridgerunner: Thanks! I had planned to do this but forgot it completely when writing the regex...

Answer (score 2):

Your input doesn't look like a valid string (unless you escape the quotes in them) but you can do it without regex too:

```
string input = "href=\"http://www.test.com/cat/1-one_piece_episodes/\"href=\"http://www.test.com/cat/2-movies_english_subbed/\"href=\"http://www.test.com/cat/3-english_dubbed/\"href=\"http://www.exclude.com\"";

List<string> matches = new List<string>();

foreach(var match in input.split(new string[]{"href"})) {
   if(!match.Contains("exclude.com"))
      matches.Add("href" + match);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this do the job?

```
href="(?!http://[^/"]+exclude.com)(.*?)[^#]"
```