# Regular expression in .net to get a special tag

Tags: c#, regex

There is a sample html code like below:

```
<div><span>span1</span></div>
<b>for test</b>
<span>span2</span>
```

Is there any way to get all span tags that are not in div tags (In this sample: span2)

According to this post [C# Regular Expression excluding a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956010/c-sharp-regular-expression-excluding-a-string) this is my pattern but it does not work.
pattern: `((?:(?!\b<div>\b))*)((.|\n)*?)<span>((.|\n)*?)</span>((.|\n)*?)((?:(?!\b</div>\b))*)`

Comment: How about using a HTML parser?

Answer (score 3):

You really don't want to be using regular expressions to try to parse HTML. You can read more about the many reasons on this Stack Overflow question:
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

You should use an HTML parser like [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), or even a simple XML parser like [XMLReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d83k261(v=vs.71).aspx)